# loop through label values and add unique word depending on index

Tags: jquery, label, each

I have a set of radio buttons with labels that I would like to add different words to depending on which index your looping through. IE: a apple, b bob, c cab, d dash

My html:

```
 <div id="charity-mod">
  <div>
   <input id="A-1" type="radio" value="A">
   <label id="chars" for="A-1">a</label>

   <input id="B-1" type="radio" value="B">
   <label id="chars" for="B-1">b</label>

   <input id="C-1" type="radio" value="C">
   <label id="chars" for="C-1">c</label>

   <input id="D-1" type="radio" value="D">
   <label id="chars" for="D-1">d</label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#charity-mod label').each(function(index){
  switch (index) {
   case 0:
      $('#chars').eq(index).after("<b>apple</b>");
      break;
    case 1:
      $('#chars').eq(index).after("<b>bob</b>");
      break;
    case 2:
      $('#chars').eq(index).after("<b>cab</b>");
      break;
    case 3:
      $('#chars').eq(index).after("<b>dash</b>");
      break;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID attribute is expected to be an unique identifier, thus, you need to change from  `<label id="chars" for="A-1">a</label>` to `<label class="chars" for="A-1">a</label>`

Doing so, you can even go for a cleaner jQuery:

```
var words = ["apple", "bob","cab", "dash"];

    $('.chars').each(function(index){
      $('#chars').eq(index).after("<b>"+words[index]+"</b>");
    }
});
```

Comment: If an answer is correct, please mark as so, otherwise stackoverflow won't ever know that your problem has been solved. Consider up vote answers that were somewhat useful. This helps other users with similar questions to find answers more easily